# Using sql database driver

Tags: sql, go

Could an end-user (development or production) please recommend an Sql driver package that preferably uses the "database/sql" package. I'm interested in Postgres, ODBC, MySql (and possibly something else but for high-volume - ie. not Sqlite) that can preferably be used on Windows and/or Linux (preferably both). To be of interest to me it likely needs to have recently been updated /maintained and must work with latest Go release. Efficiency (throughput) is obviously important. Any relevant comments are welcome.

Comment: In a project I worked on in the past we had the most success with postgres in go, but I can't remember which of the couple drivers we chose.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

GO-SQL-Driver(MySQL):

> https://github.com/Go-SQL-Driver/MySQL

Sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE `userinfo` (
    `uid` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `username` VARCHAR(64) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `departname` VARCHAR(64) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `created` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`uid`)
)

CREATE TABLE `userdetail` (
    `uid` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `intro` TEXT NULL,
    `profile` TEXT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`uid`)
)
```

Sample code:

```
package main

import (
    _ "github.com/Go-SQL-Driver/MySQL"
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "reckhou:reckhou@/test?charset=utf8")
    checkErr(err)

    //Insert
    stmt, err := db.Prepare("INSERT userinfo SET username=?,departname=?,created=?")
    checkErr(err)

    res, err := stmt.Exec("reckhou", "IT", "2010-10-02")
    checkErr(err)

    id, err := res.LastInsertId()
    checkErr(err)

    fmt.Println(id)

    // Update
    stmt, err = db.Prepare("update userinfo set username=? where uid=?")
    checkErr(err)

    res, err = stmt.Exec("update", id)
    checkErr(err)

    affect, err := res.RowsAffected()
    checkErr(err)

    fmt.Println(affect)

    //Query
    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM userinfo")
    checkErr(err)

    for rows.Next() {
        var uid int
        var username string
        var department string
        var created string
        err = rows.Scan(&uid, &username, &department, &created)
        checkErr(err)
        fmt.Println(uid)
        fmt.Println(username)
        fmt.Println(department)
        fmt.Println(created)
    }

    //Delete
    stmt, err = db.Prepare("delete from userinfo where uid=?")
    checkErr(err)

    res, err = stmt.Exec(id)
    checkErr(err)

    affect, err = res.RowsAffected()
    checkErr(err)

    fmt.Println(affect)

    db.Close()

}

func checkErr(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

PostgreSQL:

> https://github.com/bmizerany/pq

Sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE userinfo
(
    uid serial NOT NULL,
    username character varying(100) NOT NULL,
    departname character varying(500) NOT NULL,
    Created date,
    CONSTRAINT userinfo_pkey PRIMARY KEY (uid)
)
WITH (OIDS=FALSE);

CREATE TABLE userdeatail
(
    uid integer,
    intro character varying(100),
    profile character varying(100)
)
WITH(OIDS=FALSE);
```

Sample code:

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/bmizerany/pq"
)

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "user=reckhou password=reckhou dbname=test sslmode=disable")
    checkErr(err)

    //Insert
    stmt, err := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO userinfo(username,departname,created) VALUES($1,$2,$3) RETURNING uid")
    checkErr(err)

    res, err := stmt.Exec("reckhou", "IT", "2010-10-01")
    checkErr(err)

    id, err := res.LastInsertId()
    checkErr(err)

    fmt.Println(id)

    // Update
    stmt, err = db.Prepare("update userinfo set username=$1 where uid=$2")
    checkErr(err)

    res, err = stmt.Exec("update", 1)
    checkErr(err)

    affect, err := res.RowsAffected()
    checkErr(err)

    fmt.Println(affect)

    // Query
    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM userinfo")
    checkErr(err)

    for rows.Next() {
        var uid int
        var username string
        var department string
        var created string
        err = rows.Scan(&uid, &username, &department, &created)
        checkErr(err)
        fmt.Println(uid)
        fmt.Println(username)
        fmt.Println(department)
        fmt.Println(created)
    }

    // Delete
    stmt, err = db.Prepare("delete from userinfo where uid=$1")
    checkErr(err)

    res, err = stmt.Exec(1)
    checkErr(err)

    affect, err = res.RowsAffected()
    checkErr(err)

    fmt.Println(affect)

    db.Close()

}

func checkErr(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Are you actively using either of these drivers, and if so what is your experience? My preference is probably with Postgres, however one reason for me posting the question is a problem that I have on Windows with pq. I last downloaded pq to retry on 14-Apr-2013, and that problem has not been fixed. A brief description is that on Windows running with internet connected, it runs extremely slowly (a factor of around 40), including with the inbuilt tests. With internet disconnected it is probably as expected or at least that factor faster. (Issue #69)

Comment: @BrianOh I'm not using windows now, can't give you advice about this. I think it's not driver's fault, you should check your network and install settings, or move DB to Linux.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I need to use Windows for other software that I'm using and also prefer something that works on both. I don't think that it is the network or settings, because psql and other database software run without a problem and very fast. Perhaps it is my connection settings for pq, but I don't know, and no one has suggested to change them.

Comment: Reck: I did some preliminary tests on the MySql driver, and it appears to be OK thus far. It doesn't suffer the same speed degradation on Windows when internet connected to broadband via ethernet. Tests are only preliminary at this stage, but I'm impressed. Of course, MySql is owned by Oracle.

Comment: The driver just do simple things, network & DB settings & disk I/O mainly impacts the performance. You can ask for performance issue advice on dba site.

Comment: Does this library have a special "Insert or Update" setup? I tried to use "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" to no avail.