# INSERT datetime using now() with Go

Tags: mysql, go

[Using sql database driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16054317/using-sql-database-driver)

I've been referencing the post above. But having troubling doing an INSERT statement where one of my fields are for datetime. I tried doing "NOW()" but when I check the mysql db, i am seeing 0000-00-00 00:00:00. Anyone know what I can use as the value to properly have it insert the datetime?

Also- I know I can construct datetime using go's time package, but I do not wish to use the timestamp of the machine running Go. I want the datetime of the machine running mysql. Hency, why I used "NOW()".

```
stmt, err := db.Prepare("INSERT userinfo SET username=?,departname=?,created=?")
checkErr(err)

res, err := stmt.Exec("reckhou", "IT", "NOW()")
checkErr(err)

id, err := res.LastInsertId()
checkErr(err)

fmt.Println(id)
```

Comment: post your SQL!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: the exclamations were just to satisfy the min length comment....  i'm not yelling.... yet.

Comment: Get rid of the ? for now and simply put the command in.  E.g. `insert into userinfo set username=?, department=?, created=now();`

Answer (score 16):

The `NOW()` needs to be part of the SQL text, it's not a bind value.

```
INSERT userinfo SET username=?,departname=?,created=NOW()
```

The way you have it coded, MySQL is seeing `"NOW()"` as a literal string, as if it were any old string like `'foo'`. MySQL is casting that string value to a DATETIME (MySQL is expecting a format close to `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'`, and it's failing to cast that to a valid date. We'd expect either a NULL or a special "zero-date" like you are seeing.

Answer (score 14):

```
var datetime = time.Now()
dt := datetime.Format(time.RFC3339)
_, err = DatabaseHandle.Exec("INSERT into userinfo(id, date) VALUES (?,?)", 0, dt)
```

Beware that this will set the current time of the server running the go code, which might be different from the MySQL Server (might not be the same timezone, etc.)

Comment: [Time.Format](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format) returns a string, so you should do `datetime := time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339)` rather than calling it and ignoring the return value

Comment: Thanks for the tip nevernew.

Comment: Beware that this will set the current time of the server running the go code, which might be different from the MySQL Server (might not be the same timezone, etc.)

Comment: `datetime.Format(time.RFC3339)`  doesn't work out !